# constructed generic type in cref part of xml-comment

Tags: c#, generics, xml-comments

I have generic exception class like this:

```
public class DuplicateException<TEntity> : Exception
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

And I have non-generic method which might throw constructed generic exception:

```
void Save()
{
    throw new DuplicateException<SomeEntity>();
}
```

This method may throw this generic exception but only of this one constructed type `DuplicateException<SomeEntity>` and it cannot throw this exception with some other type parameter instead of `SomeEntity`.

Now I want to specify this fact in xml-comment for `Save` method. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/11/750056.aspx) describes a little bit how to comment methods with generic exception and I've tried these two alternatives:

1) Inserts by defauly by autocomplete in VS:

```
/// <exception cref="DuplicateException{TEntity}" />
```

2)  Replaced `TEntity` with `SomeEntity`

```
/// <exception cref="DuplicateException{SomeEntity}" />
```

But in both cases output XML still states that this method might throw generic **non-constructed** type which doesn't mention `SomeEntity` at all:

```
<exception cref="T:MyNameSpace.DuplicateException`1" />
```

Comment: Is it necessary to throw a generic exception? The only use of that would be if a particular code fragment could potentially throw DuplicateException<TEntityA> and DuplicateException<TEntityB>, and you only want to catch one but not the other.

Comment: Ok, but why not just have a single DuplicateException that could be thrown from any Save* method? Why does it need to be generic?

Comment: Being strongly typed doesn't really get you much. Yes, you can have a strongly typed property with the object that was being saved. But what are you going to do with that strongly typed property? I think you are going to be better off with a non-generic exception here.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the cref attribute is to link to the documentation for a type. But there is no documentation for concrete generic types, so it's not surprising that the generated cref attribute is for the generic type definition. Your concern is that you want to display something different that what is in the link. You can do that when using the  element, because the content of the element is the text of the link. But in the  element, the content of the element is the description of when the exception occurs. So I don't think there is a way to do what you are looking for.